# Showing max y-axis with CorePlot CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic setting

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I want to plot a figure which have the max y axis value label showing on the label tick with CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic setting. However I haven't found any public function allow me to do that.

After checking CorePlot source code (autoGenerateMajorTickLocations method) I think I can do some workaround by using CPTDecimalDivide and CPTNiceNum. I implemented my code by increasing my plotRange in Y axis with the calculated "nice number" interval

```
var majorInterval = CPTDecimalDivide( Decimal(yAxisLength), 
CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(5-1))
majorInterval = CPTNiceNum(majorInterval)

let interval = Int(truncating: majorInterval as NSNumber)
let number = Int(yAxisLength/interval) + 1
yAxisLength = Int(Double(number * interval))
```

However the CPTNiceNum is not a public method so I am wondering are there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the graph to make sure the axis labels are updated and then read the `majorTickLocations` set from the y-axis. You can find the max location value in the set easily.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I also need the data about tick interval, is majorIntervalLength or majorTickLength corresponded to that value? but they are all default value even I run the relabel() and updateMajorTickLabels()

Comment: Ok, I think both majorIntervalLength or majorTickLength are for setting the desired property not getting the information under CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic setting. Is there any other way to get the tick interval? Or I have to calculate it by majorTickLocations set?

Comment: The tick length is the length of the tick marks drawn on the axis. It has nothing to do with the spacing between the tick marks. The `majorIntervalLength` is an input to the fixed interval labeling policy and gives the desired distance between major tick marks. It is ignored for the other labeling policies. To find the interval between ticks, put the location set in an array, sort it, and find the distance between two adjacent locations.